# JavaDB ( derby ) path to database?

Tags: java, derby, javadb

Using the embedded driver I can connect to my derby database using the JDBC url:

```
jdbc:derby:mydbname
```

But, I usually put the full path for the db like:

```
jdbc:derby:/Users/oreyes/dbs/mydbname
```

Is there a way I can just specify the db name and have something like a "db_path" or something like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not an expert with derby, setting `derby.system.home` as described in [developers guide](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/dev/devguide/cdevdvlp27610.html) seems to work as you expect.

Comment: That's the one I have just found ( a minute ago :P ) ... I'll try it.

Comment: That worked, now I have to find out how to specify that property so maven can see it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3231797/specify-system-property-to-maven-project