# Cannot access properties set in Maven's pom.xml, System.getProperty returns always null

Tags: java, maven, properties, junit

I try to set up properties in my pom.xml and access them during my jUnit test.
The class I want to read them in, is imported by the jUnit `Test.java` and is using
`String prop = System.getProperty("target1");`
but it always is null. What I tried in my pom.xml already:

```xml
...
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>default</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <target1>2948</target1>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

and also

```xml
...
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.15</version>
   <systemPropertyVariables>
      <target2>2948</target2>
   </systemPropertyVariables>
   <systemProperties>
     <property>
        <name>target3</name>
        <value>2948</value>
     </property>
   </systemProperties>
...
</configuration>
...
```

I do have a parent pom.xml but that can't be the problem can it?
I'm using Netbeans and starting the Tests by hiting "Test File" on the pom.xml

Thanks yous :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about maven-failsafe-plugin, but I am able to get the result by adding property and value in maven-surefire-plugin since that is what is used by junit tests in a maven project. Here is a detailed explanation: [Specify system property to Maven project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3231797/specify-system-property-to-maven-project)

from the maven site (http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/) - "The Failsafe Plugin is designed to run integration tests while the Surefire Plugins is designed to run unit tests". Since you are running a junit, you should add your property to surefire plugin.

Comment: awww, stupid me... thats what you get from copying code :) switching to surefire ofc solved it, thanks a lot.