# Spring Profiles: Simple example of ActiveProfilesResolver?

Tags: java, spring, maven

**what am I doing?**
I have an app that I want to test across different environments - dev, staging, etc

**What I do?**
I am using `maven cargo` plugin to deploy application war to run integration tests.

**What I need?**
I need to my test to infer the `spring.profiles.active` based on environment variable set by cargo like

```
                    <container>
                        <containerId>tomcat7x</containerId>
                        <systemProperties>
                            <spring.profiles.active>development</spring.profiles.active>
                        </systemProperties>
                    </container>
```

**Why?**
so that I can remove the hard coding in my Integration Test `@ActiveProfiles("development")` and the test can infer what active profile is from environment variable

**Question**
- I found [Spring integration tests with profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20551681/spring-integration-tests-with-profile/20571356#20571356) which mentions about using `ActiveProfilesResolver`
- I tried to find how can I make use of it, but could not find any resources
I am looking for guidance/recommendations on how to use `ActiveProfilesResolver`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try this. I learned from different places and created the following. It works for me

```
public class SpringActiveProfileResolver implements ActiveProfilesResolver {

    @Override
    public String[] resolve(final Class<?> aClass) {
        final String activeProfile = System.getProperty("spring.profiles.active");
        return new String[] { activeProfile == null ? "integration" : activeProfile };
    }
}
```

and on you test class do this

```
@ActiveProfiles(resolver = SpringActiveProfileResolver.class)
public class IT1DataSetup {
......
}
```