# Rollback Integration Test which uses cucumber and tests the application on embedded tomcat via maven

Tags: spring, integration-testing, rollback, cucumber-jvm, embedded-tomcat-7

I am trying to set up an integration test framework for my spring project using cucumber framework and selenium for UI automation.

What I have done till now is

1. Use tomcat7 plugin for maven and deploy my war file to this embedded tomcat
2. Use the cucumber feature file to specify any test cases, be it a rest service or for the UI automation
3. We need to use our existing development DB for test purposes
   I will hit the app url for the application running on the embedded tomcat.

What I am unable to find out is, can we rollback a transaction automatically after the test is done?

I am able to rollback transactions from cucumber/junit that were directly using my DAO as the DB connection was initiated from the same spring context.

But when the invocations are made using this model, I am unable to find any idea to rollback the transactions after the tests are done.

Answer (score 0):

Can you think of achieving your integration testing in terms of Spring profile? You can create a spring profile for integration test and use it as environment variable or using annotations to specify rollback for transaction.

Take a look at following references to get an idea:

[Spring integration tests with profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20551681/spring-integration-tests-with-profile)

https://spring.io/blog/2011/06/21/spring-3-1-m2-testing-with-configuration-classes-and-profiles