# Spring Boot DataJpaTest unit test reverting to H2 instead of mySql

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, spring-data-jpa

I've got a simple little "hello world" Spring Boot app.  It has a single entity ("IssueReport") and it's configured to run mySQL (instead of the default H2 embedded database).

The app itself runs fine.  I created a mySql database and user, Spring Boot/Hibernate created the table and successfully populates and reads the mySQL data when I run the app.  Life is Good - there are no problems with mySQL and my Spring Boot app itself.

Q: Now how do I use mySQL (instead of the embedded H2) in unit tests?

1. I created a second, separate mySQL database: `test2_test_db`.
2. I'm using Spring Boot 2.0.6; Eclipse Photon on STS 3.9.6; Ubuntu Linux.
3. I created `application-test.properties` in `src/test/resources/`:

   ```
   spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test2_test_db
   spring.datasource.username=springuser
   spring.datasource.password=springuser
   spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
   ```
4. Here's the entire unit test:

   ```
   package com.hellospring.example;

   import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;
   import java.util.List;
   import javax.transaction.Transactional;
   import org.junit.Test;
   import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
   import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
   import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTest;
   import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.TestEntityManager;
   import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;
   import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
   import com.hellospring.example.entity.IssueReport;
   import com.hellospring.example.repositories.IssueRepository;

   @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
   @ActiveProfiles("test")
   @Transactional
   @DataJpaTest
   public class IssueRepositoryIntegrationTests {

        @Autowired
        private TestEntityManager entityManager;

        @Autowired
        private IssueRepository issueRepository;

        @Test
        public void addNewIssue() {
            System.out.println("addNewIssue()...");  // <-- This prints in the console
            final String email = "test@test.io";
            List<IssueReport> resultSet = issueRepository.findAll();  // <-- We get an exception in here...
        }  
   }
   ```
5. Here's the console error:

   ```
   2018-10-25 22:20:16.381  INFO 13637 --- [           main] c.v.e.IssueRepositoryIntegrationTests    : The following profiles are active: test
   2018-10-25 22:20:16.405  INFO 13637 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@d554c5f: startup date [Thu Oct 25 22:20:16 PDT 2018]; root of context hierarchy
   2018-10-25 22:20:17.059  INFO 13637 --- [           main] beddedDataSourceBeanFactoryPostProcessor : Replacing 'dataSource' DataSource bean with embedded version
   2018-10-25 22:20:17.060  INFO 13637 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'dataSource' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari; factoryMethodName=dataSource; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]] with [Root bean: class [org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.jdbc.TestDatabaseAutoConfiguration$EmbeddedDataSourceFactoryBean]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null]
   2018-10-25 22:20:17.308  INFO 13637 --- [           main] o.s.j.d.e.EmbeddedDatabaseFactory        : Starting embedded database: url='jdbc:h2:mem:979b3ce9-604e-4efd-a6d4-79576c3d67e9;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=false', username='sa'
   2018-10-25 22:20:17.685  INFO 13637 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
     ...  <= I do *NOT* want H2!  I want mySQL!

   2018-10-25 22:20:19.315  WARN 13637 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 42102, SQLState: 42S02
   2018-10-25 22:20:19.316 ERROR 13637 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Table "ISSUE_REPORT" not found; SQL statement:
     ...  <= Here's the exception from running the test...
   ```

Q: What's the EASIEST change so I can run my unit tests with mySQL, just as I'm able to run my Spring Boot app with mySQL?

Q: Is "@DataJpaTest" the best choice here, or should I try a different annotation?

Q: Must I create a separate "Bean" class?  If so, can you point to an example?

================================================================

Thank you for all your replies. Including Simon Martinelli's (now deleted) response.

RESOLUTION:

1. My original `application-test.properties` was OK as-is.
2. I put it in the wrong place: *all* application.properties files for *any* profile should typically go in the same project folder: `src/main/resources`

   <= EXAMPLE: `src/main/resources/application-test.properties`
3. `@Transactional` wasn't relevant here - I removed it.  I kept it `@ActiveProfiles("test")`.
4. Per Karthik R's suggestion, I added `@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace=Replace.NONE)`.
5. At that point, the test successfully read `application-test.properties` and used MySQL instead of H2.
6. Final annotations:

   ```
   @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
   @ActiveProfiles("test")
   @DataJpaTest
   @AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace=Replace.NONE)
   public class IssueRepositoryIntegrationTests {
   ```

I found this link particularly helpful: [Spring Boot – Profile based properties and yaml example](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-profile-based-properties-and-yaml-example/)

<= I've always found all the material on http://www.mkyong.com extremely good!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

By default, the `@DataJpaTest` uses in memory H2 database for repo tests. Should you need to use the actual DB, you can consider either to disable the auto Configurations or use `@SpringBootTest` where the whole application web mvc is enabled.

**To disable auto config:**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@Transactional
@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace=Replace.NONE)
public class IssueRepositoryIntegrationTests
```

`@AutoConfigureTestDatabase` configures the test H2 DB for you. You can specifically mention not to by above or you can exclude this auto configuration as :

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude=AutoConfigureTestDatabase.class)
```

**P.S:** : I have not tried the above exclusion myself yet.

**For more info on that go thru javadoc:** https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/jdbc/AutoConfigureTestDatabase.html

Comment: i only got problem with decrypt, i use   @DataJpaTest and password is encrypt with jasypt, it could not connect to db using jasypt for testing

Comment: could you please describe how do you encrypt your password ? i do use jasypt and with datajpatest it does not work, ignores the encryptation ...

Comment: Thanks that was very useful.
I was not understanding why my integration tests following the tutorial: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-testing-separate-data-source were able to use the data source i selected via PropertySource annotation, but my usual tests that had the DataJpaTest annotation eneded up with a non desirable DB.  With this AutoCOnfigureTestDatabse I am application to acutally use for example application-postgres.properties. This is good.

Comment: `@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace=Replace.NONE)` works for me and saved my day. Whole day I was debugging every corner and searched huge number of resources but didn't found the reason for enabling auto configured database. This is a great solution.

Comment: you can also use to property `spring.test.database.replace=none`. Here is the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#appendix.application-properties.testing)

Answer (score 1):

From `@DataJpaTest` [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/DataJpaTest.html):

> By default, tests annotated with @DataJpaTest will use an embedded
>   in-memory database (replacing any explicit or usually auto-configured
>   DataSource).

If you go to documentation you can see this annotation aggregates a lot of other annotations.

`@Transactional` annotation behaves in different way in test context than in application context:

From spring [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#testcontext-tx-enabling-transactions):

> Annotating a test method with @Transactional causes the test to be run
>   within a transaction that is, by default, automatically rolled back
>   after completion of the test.

I believe I provided enough information which answering your question, additionaly you can take a look at following articles:

[Configuring Separate Spring DataSource for Tests](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-testing-separate-data-source)
[Testing with @Configuration Classes and Profiles](https://spring.io/blog/2011/06/21/spring-3-1-m2-testing-with-configuration-classes-and-profiles)