# Getting variables from pom.xml java

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, maven

I am using eclipse with maven for a mobile automation test on a mobile webpage.

I am defining the following in my pom.xml

```
<properties>
    <MY_VARIABLE>www.google.com/</MY_VARIABLE>
</properties>
```

but when i am calling this using

```
String testurl1 = System.getProperty("MY_VARIABLE");
```

it always seems to return null.

I also tried the following way of defining variable

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.16</version>
    <configuration>
        <systemPropertyVariables>
        <MY_VARIABLE>www.google.com</MY_VARIABLE>
        </systemPropertyVariables>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

but still am getting the value as null.

I could use some help
Thanks.

Comment: You should use a property file for that

Comment: I think there is a mixup of variable names. The property you use us MY_VARIABLE but in the surefire plugin config its MY_URL / MY_VARIABLE? The way you have with the surefire plugin should work, you may just use the wrong name?

Comment: @wemu i am not using MY_VARIABLE twice in my code anywhere either the first method or the second method...

Comment: @RC. could you explain a little further ..

Comment: just the xml you have there cannot be valid: <MY_URL>www.google.com</MY_VARIABLE>

Comment: @wemu sorry that was a typo..

Comment: no problem. just wanted to make sure its not a typo issue :) this may be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3231797/specify-system-property-to-maven-project

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your configuration will not work in eclipse since there is no good m2e support for surefire. The maven surefire plugin forkes a new process and provides the `systemPropertyVariables` to it. Your configuration will work if you run the tests from the command-line, e.g.

```
mvn surefire:test
```

To make it run in both worlds (command-line and eclipse) I do it this way...

1. Create a  `src/test/resources/maven.properties`
2. Edit the `maven.properties` file and put the properties you need in it, e.g.

   ```
   project.build.directory=${project.build.directory}
   MY_VARIABLE=${MY_VARIABLE}
   ```
3. Enable resource filtering for test resources

   ```
   <build>
       <testResources>
           <testResource>
               <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
               <filtering>true</filtering>
           </testResource>
       </testResources>
       ...
   </build>
   ```
4. Load the properties in your test and access them

   ```
    Properties mavenProps = new Properties();
    InputStream in = TestClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/maven.properties");
    mavenProps.load(in);

    String buildDir = mavenProps.getProperty("project.build.directory");
    String myVar = mavenProps.getProperty("MY_VARIABLE");
   ```

Comment: so i have to add just this line in the maven.properties file 
MY_VARIABLE = www.google.com
and how do i call the variable after mavenProps.load(in); command ...

Comment: thanks it worked just one more question for you i can just use the MY_VARIABLE from the maven.properties in my pom.xml by just ${MY_VARIABLE} right ?

Comment: @Ram Yes that's right, because when maven filters the `maven.properties` file it replaces all occurrences of `${...}` with the value of the property. Take a look at http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html for more info.

Comment: Could you tell me how do i call a variable that i have defined in the surefire plugin is it same as mavenProps.get() because System.getPropoerty() does not work

Comment: I updated my answer in order to explain why it does not work when you start the junit tests in eclipse.

Comment: I was able to access the properties in Eclipse while running JUnit tests. I just added a line to my java code see it here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26464371/java-unable-to-read-variables-from-pom)