# Java unable to read variables from pom

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have the following line in my maven.properties file.

```
   MY_VARIABLE = www.google.com
```

My pom file code looks like this

```
    <build>

    <pluginManagement>
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.16</version>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*Test*.java</include>
                                <include>**/*Tests*.java</include>
                                <include>**/Test*.java</include>
                            </includes>
                            <files>
                                <file>src/test/resources/maven.properties</file>
                            </files>

                            <systemPropertyVariables>
                                <message>${MY_VARIABLE}</message>
                            </systemPropertyVariables>

                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>

            </plugin>


            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.16</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

And finally i have a piece of code to retrieve the value in the message variable.

```
   public static String getMsg() 
   {
      final String msg = System.getProperty("message");
      if (StringUtils.isEmpty(msg) || url.startsWith("${")) 
      {
          return "Empty message";
      }
      return msg;
   }
```

So when i am calling the getMsg() method, it always returns the value of msg as Empty Message.

Is it some error in the pom.xml declaration or is it some problem in the getMsg() function that is being used.

It would be nice of someone could throw some light on this.

Thanks in advance ....

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, you need to use the following syntax

```
<properties>
  <message>${MY_VARIABLE}</message>
</properties>
```

systemPropertyVariables are for the Surefire pluging, for unit testing

Comment: I have a doubt here since the MY_VARIABLE is declared in the maven.properties file which is in another directory (src/test/resources) will it not throw an error if i do this directly ..
How do i naviate to the directory first ?

Comment: A problem might be that you are using the wrong plugin for unit tests. From the maven site "The Failsafe Plugin is designed to run integration tests while the Surefire Plugins is designed to run unit tests." You might want to change to the Surefire plugin if you are intending to run unit tests.

Comment: thanks for the reply but it does not work with the surefire plugin also .. :(

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem some time ago. I don't know if it is a failsafe/maven bug or limitation. The solution I found was to set the variable as a VM argument. Here is how it currently works for me:

Update you pom as follows:

```
                   <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.17</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <argLine>-DMY_VARIABLE=${MY_VARIABLE}</argLine>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>test</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>integration-test</goal>
                                    <goal>verify</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
```

Then, you can invoke maven to get your integration tests running as follows:
    mvn integration-test -DMY_VARIABLE=www.google.com

Comment: I am not familiar with running maven from the command line i am using it for my JUnit mobile automation scripts so could you explain a little further .

Comment: thanks just one more question.
since the MY_VARIABLE is in another file how do i access it ..

Comment: You can provide directly the value of the variable in your command line or use an intermediate shell variable. For example, for a unix system, it would look like: MY_VARIABLE=$(cat maven.properties)

Comment: i am using eclipse on windows so could you give an example to describe what you are saying .

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Guys for helping ..

I found a way to get this done.

Before i start the tests, in my java file i am using

```
 System.setProperty("message" , "welcome message");
```

And this is finally printing out the value instead of null.

Cheers