# Jenkins Extended Choice Parameter multiple variables

Tags: maven, jenkins, testng

I have my extender parameter like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytzPk.png

how can i pass it to maven ?

```
<systemPropertyVariables>
<modules>${project.modules}</modules>
</systemPropertyVariables>
```

seems not working ? how to access exact one? will it be store in table ?
what if I pick more than one ?

i would like to access it in testng:

```
String modules = System.getProperty("modules");
```

Comment: choosing two params gives for example: two,three, how to get only one? something like ${FIRST.modules} ?

Comment: If you want only one parameter always you should change its type to **Single select** or **Radio buttons** instead of *Check boxes*. Then you can pass it as an argument on the maven `Goals and options` input with `-DargLine="-DpropertyName=propertyValue"` (complete details [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3231797/specify-system-property-to-maven-project))

Comment: @morfic but i want to pass couple of params and then access one by one

Comment: Then pass it as a list like you are doing it now, and split it inside your test after comma (`,`)

Comment: yes, in java its simple using regex but how to do this in maven pom.xml,     <modules>${modules}</modules>, how can i access ${modules} - first ? second ?

Comment: At this point your question is unclear so please update it to reflect where the problem is. Supposing you're trying to build only some modules depending on your selection, you could try defining separate [profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) for each module and activate them with the setting from jenkins `-P ${Modules}`