# Access properties of maven property plugin

Tags: java, maven, properties-file

I included the maven property plugin like proposed in a response to this question [Specify system property to Maven project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3231797/specify-system-property-to-maven-project). In order to be able to set my database properties from file (and override it with maven parameters in testing environment). However if I try to access one of the properties via
`System.getProperty("mysql.url")` for example `null` is returned. How can I access the properties set from set properties goal.

```java
private void initializeDatabaseConfiguration() {
    url = System.getProperty("mysql.url");
    con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
}
```

And my maven plugin is defined like this:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-alpha-2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>initialize</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>set-system-properties</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <files>                          
                    <file>src/main/resources/config.properties</file>
                </files>
                <properties>
                    <property>
                        <name>mysql.url</name>
                        <value>${mysql.url}</value>
                    </property>
                </properties>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add phase:

```
<execution>
<phase>initialize</phase>
 <goals>
   <goal>set-system-properties</goal>
 </goals>
```

If you use the phase initialize, you can use the propriets after phase 'initialize'

Comment: This did not change anything

Comment: I want to use it in a method where a database connection is obtained like shown in the edited code

Comment: When you use this method initializeDatabaseConfiguration, if you use executable-jar whit main-class , you can use  resources>filtering?

Comment: could you give a more detailed answer how I would use resoure filtering to do this?

Answer (score 0):

There is a goal, called `read-project-properties`. You need to use this goal to read properties from the specific file/files e.t.c. [Check please the docs](https://github.com/Mikhail2048/properties-maven-plugin). This way you will be able to load maven properties into build process.

This is the first thing. The second thing is - `System.getProperty()` will not pick up the properties you have defined for maven build. This properties are just for maven build, they will not be passed right to your JVM. So `properties-maven-plugin` is not really what you want here. To be able to access parameters with `System.getProperty("some-parameter")`, you need to pass `-Dsome-parameter=value` to `java` command.