# IntelliJ IDEA says that <systemProperties/> element is not allowed inside <configuration/>

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, jetty

I'm using a plugin in maven that uses Jetty.

In this plugin, I need to made a configuration to set `maxFormContentSize`:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.organization.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-example-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${example.version}</version>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- -->
    </dependencies>
    <configuration>
        <systemProperties>
            <systemProperty>
            <name>org.mortbay.jetty.Request.maxFormContentSize</name>
                <value>500000</value>
            </systemProperty>
        </systemProperties>
        <script>${example.script}</script>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The problem is that Intellij IDEA says that systemProperties element is not allowed here:

```
Element systemProperties is not allowed here
```

What is the correct configuration for the IntelliJ IDEA not show this error? I already made a [research about this subject](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3231981/2387977) but appears that is the only possible configuration.

I'm using maven 2.2.1 and IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.4. The Jetty version is 7.6.8.v20121106.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `<configuration>` section of a maven plugin can only contain what that specific plugin supports in its various goals.

Not all maven plugins support `<systemProperties>` only certain ones do.

Since you stubbed out the actual plugin you are struggling with I cannot link you to the specific plugin's documentation page for its goals and configurations.

Look for something like this ...

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/javadoc-mojo.html

... but for your specific plugin

**Ask Maven**

You can also ask maven, on its command line, to describe the plugin and even a specific goal in the plugin.

> Note: the below example command lines work with [`maven-help-plugin`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/describe-mojo.html) v2.2 or better.

Describe all of the goals:

```
$ mvn help:describe -DgroupId=org.eclipse.jetty \
                    -DartifactId=jetty-maven-plugin \
                    -Dversion=9.4.6.v20170531
```

Describe a specific goal in detail (with parameters):

```
$ mvn help:describe -DgroupId=org.eclipse.jetty \
                    -DartifactId=jetty-maven-plugin \
                    -Dversion=9.4.6.v20170531 \
                    -Dgoal=start \
                    -Ddetail=true
```

Comment: I thought this setting was a maven pattern, not the plugin itself. That explains a lot. Thank you! The plugin is MyContainer (https://github.com/murer/mycontainer), but it is not well documented.