# how to remove system property in maven pom.xml

Tags: java, maven

Is there any good way / plugin to remove system properties in maven pom.xml ?

I need this ability because i am doing code generation based on System properties and this causes issue if i run mvn clean install in the parent module where it has multi sub module as system properties will remain the last value if i dont clear it.

Clearly i can do this by create my own plugin / main class util to do this . bust just want to find out if there are already existing solution out there.

Thanks

Comment: Check this [Specify system property to Maven project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13159023/5525384) and [Properties Maven Plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/set-system-properties-mojo.html).

Comment: This is a bit vague. Are you having trouble with System properties in unit tests?

Comment: Check out **Maven Surefire Plugin**. You can set system properties using its's configuration

Comment: Some system properties are fixed. It depends which one you want to change