# Pass Cucumber tags from command line with mvn test

Tags: cucumber

Runner file

```
package cucumberOptions;

import io.cucumber.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;
import io.cucumber.testng.CucumberOptions;


@CucumberOptions(features = "src/test/java/features", glue = "stepDefinitions", monochrome = true, tags = "@MutualFund", plugin = {
        "pretty", "html:target/cucumber.html", "json:target/cucumber.json","com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter:" })

public class TestNGRunner extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {

}
```

here how can i override tags while running tests from mvn test? also is it possible that when i dont override the tag, the tag present in test runner should be called?

Able to override with static block

```
@CucumberOptions(features = "src/test/java/features", glue = "stepDefinitions", monochrome = true,
            plugin = {"pretty", "html:target/cucumber.html", "json:target/cucumber.json",
                    "com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter:"})
    public class Inner extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {
    }

    static {
        String tags = System.getProperty("tags", "@demo");
        System.setProperty("cucumber.filter.tags", tags);
    }
```

But wondering do we have any cleaner method?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Specify system property to Maven project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3231797/specify-system-property-to-maven-project)